# Fixed margin in header and footer

Tags: margins, fancyhdr, geometry

I'm creating a template for a project. In it, I've created a command to create a summary page, but I need to change the geometry to be wider than the rest of the document.
I've used the `geometry` package with the commands `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry`. This part works well.

Now I'm looking for a way to create the same header and footer across pages (this includes the same margin for all the different geometries).
To do this, I've tried calculating the left and right margins to add the margin value with the command `\fancyhfoffset` like this:

```latex
\newcommand{\leftMargin}{%
    \dimexpr% 
      1in + %
    \ifoddpage%
      \oddsidemargin%
    \else%
      \evensidemargin%
    \fi%
  \relax%
}

\newcommand{\rightMargin}{%
  \dimexpr%
    \paperwidth - \textwidth - \leftMargin%
  \relax%
}

\fancypagestyle{main}{%
  % Reset
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
  % Compute header and footer margins
  \fancyhfoffset[L]{\leftMargin - 2cm}%
  \fancyhfoffset[R]{\rightMargin - 2cm}%
  % Header
  \fancyhead[R]{\myTitle}%
  % Footer
  \fancyfoot[R]{\myLogo}%
  \fancyfoot[L]{\thepage}%
}
```

But this solution doesn't work : The margins are the same than these of the previous geometry...
And if I use the same solution for the style `plain` (`\fancypagestyle{plain}`), when the style change (for example, the next page after a chapter start), the margins are reset and now they follow the text width. I think it's not possible to use the `fancyhfoffset` inside a `fancypagestyle` declaration but I don't know how else to do it.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you extend your code fragment into a small example we can compile please? Starting with `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: It is a relative offset.  Use `\fancyhfoffset[L]{-2cm}` and `\fancyhfoffset[R]{-2cm}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geometry uses odd page margins as input, then computes the even page margins.  `\fancyhfoffset` is relative to the current margins, which obviously change with `\newgeometry`.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE onlu

\edef\leftMargin{% odd page
    \dimexpr
      1in + \oddsidemargin
    \relax
}
\edef\rightMargin{%
  \dimexpr%
    \paperwidth - \textwidth - \leftMargin% or \evensidemargin - 1in
  \relax%
}

\fancyhf{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
% Header
\fancyhead[R]{myTitle}%
% Footer
\fancyfoot[R]{myLogo}%
\fancyfoot[L]{\thepage}%
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{main}{%
  % Reset
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
  % Compute header and footer margins
  \fancyhfoffset[L]{-1cm}%
  \fancyhfoffset[R]{-1cm}%
  % Header
  \fancyhead[R]{myTitle}%
  % Footer
  \fancyfoot[R]{myLogo}%
  \fancyfoot[L]{\thepage}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]

\newgeometry{left={\dimexpr \leftMargin-1cm},right={\dimexpr \rightMargin-1cm}}
\pagestyle{main}

\lipsum[1-12]

\clearpage% print header/footer for last page
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```